# How to use shareReplay for cache HTTP response with request params

Tags: angular, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

I have a scenario like I need to fetch file content when click on a file.
I want to cache the file content API with `shareReplay()`, how can I achieve it?

`fileService.getContent` is an API service which will fetch content with `params(repository_id, filePath);`

Question:

- Where should I use the `shareReplay()` `pipe`? Inside API service? or the place I wrote below.
- **Below code does not work as expected.** The API will be triggered multi-times. How can I cache the API with `shareReplay()` to call only once.

**Component**

```js
fileOpened$ = new Subject();
...

this.fileOpened$.pipe(
    switchMap(file => this.fileService.getContent(this.repository_id, file.filePath)),
       shareReplay(1)
);
```

**service**:

```js
getContent(repoId: string, path: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get<string>(
        `/api/xxx/${repoId}/files/${decodeURIComponent(path)}`,
        {
            responseType: 'text' as 'json'
        });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would add the `shareReplay` code in the service.
Because of the parameters you can create a `Map` that caches the `Observables`.

Here the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shareobservable) I created to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks for replying, actually the code above doesn't cache the API response at all.
Every time this.fileOpened$.next(file) will trigger an API again.
Is this caused because the service always returns a new Observable?

Comment: i'm so sorry somehow my latest changes to my stackblitz were not changed. Please check the link again

Comment: Thanks! It seems we have build a cache by ourselves.

Comment: Yes, our own cache that handles the parameters but it only works because of the shareReplay.

Comment: stackblitz works, but replicating the same implementation with DB request shows it's not caching.

Answer (score 2):

The main context of service is to create a sharable code. At some place you might need fresh result always from this api, right? It's better to have `shareReplay()` in your component. Where you want it to provide you a replay. If you are sure this service method will not be used anywhere else. Having it on either side will not have any impact.

Comment: Thanks for replying, actually the code above doesn't cache the API response at all. Every time this.fileOpened$.next(file) will trigger an API again. Is this caused because the service always returns a new Observable?